Return failed conversion data in SQL Server
My company has a table in which the string dd/mm is stored for various entities and so I can compare it against some other dates (specifically for the year 2006 for example taking '01/04' and the trying to make it 01/04/2006* to then try and convert that to a datetime)
I've done the following:
convert(datetime, field + '/2006', 103)

so that it takes the dd/mm column and creates a dd/mm/yyyy string, to then convert it to a datetime value which I can then use in various comparisons.
However one of the entries in the original table of 5321 potential rows throws an error

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I've tried looking for obvious ones (leap years) and days larger than 31st etc but no luck
Is there a way of getting SQL Server to return the string it tried converting into a date but then failed? Something like
select id, convert(datetime, field + '/2006', 103) 
on error return 'error'

so that I get the primary id for row producing the error and can use that to track it down?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

select * from yourtable where try_convert(datetime,field+ '/2006',103) is null and field is not null

What you really should be doing, after you find your bad data, is correct that data and then fixing the design; a varchar column is not appropriate for storing dates. Use a date data type.

@ThomA, we don't control the database and table structures from third-party software. The field in question only stores annual renewal dates (dd/mm), as it's the same every year. I needed to compare a different date (stored in a proper date time field) with the 2006 renewal date, hence the use of dateTime fields. Although the design can't be fixed, I will highlight the data discrepancies to the relevant department for correction.

You can use TRY_CONVERT to find rows with invalid dates like:
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, field + '/2006') IS NULL
    AND field IS NOT NULL;


Always good to add AND field IS NOT NULL to avoid false positives
